# База данных для статистических данных

Tags: база-данных, nosql, highload, статистика, big-data

Есть набор быстро пополняющихся данных из большого количества источников, которые тоже пополняются. Структура предельно простая:

- id источника
- значение
- дата/время

Нужна выборка значений по произвольному промежутку даты и времени, как для одного источника, так и сумма значений со всех источников сразу. 
Это нужно для возможности динамического построения графиков за определенный промежуток времени для одного источника; либо для графика, на котором отображается сумма значений от всех источников. 
Так же, такая выборка потребуется для анализа этих данных, чтобы прогнозировать будущие значения на определенный период.

1. Какая база данных лучше всего вписывается в эту задачу и почему?
2. Подойдут ли облачные NOSQL хранилища (Google, Amazon, Azure), или дешевле поднять свой сервер с БД из ответа №1?

Answer (score 2):

**ИМХО.** NoSQL - не подойдут от слова "вааще". Они заточены по совсем другой, более "вариабельный" тип данных. При вашей простой структуре вам нужна именно реляционная база данных, так как данные из большого количества источников - то что то серверное: MSSQL, MySQL, Oracl - скорее всего любая из них справится.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас данных ОЧЕНЬ много (сотни гигабайт-терабайты/день), то посмотрите на Hadoop, там можно хранить много и считать быстро. 
Если же данных меньше - то стоит использовать PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL.
NoSQL - это не о том, он скорее о слабо структурированных данных, так что в вашем случае это просто не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как насчет хранения логов, будет действовать тот же принцип при выборе БД? По-сути, вместо числового значения будет строковое.

Comment: @HarpyWar да, тот же самый принцип. повторюсь, если логов будет много (а с текстовыми значениями довольно просто набрать терабайт), то смотрите в сторону Hadoop

Comment: Я почему спрашиваю, потому что сейчас у меня есть БД MySQL с точно такой же структурой, в ней 26 млн. записей, размер 1гб. Запрос выборки между датами работает крайне медленно (1-2 минуты). 
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `id`=41024 AND `date` BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1402072192) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1433608192) LIMIT 10;
Таблица INNODB, индекс есть как на поле id, так и на id+date. EXPLAIN тоже выдает, что индекс применяется в запросе.

Comment: Аналогичную проблему нашел здесь, но без ответа http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948113/mysql-query-very-slow-within-date-range-in-timestamp

Вот я и думаю, такое количество уже "очень много данных" для MySQL, или нужно как-то специально настраивать MySQL?